# How to read output modifiers?

Tags: kittens-game

How do I read the generation modifiers for a certain resource like catnip? I am trying to optimise the number of villagers placed in farming. When hovering over the output, I see:

```
Base:
Weather:
*Village:
*Upgrade:
Buildings:
Demand:
```

To what order are these modifiers applied? I am assuming that the Upgrades only affect the village output, and the Weather only affect base output. So then how does the buildings affect the output? Does it affect overall, Village or only base output?

Also, what does the * beside Village and Upgrade mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *'s appear to be separators in a vague sense, attempts to offset to show different tiers or sources of production, so that it will be understood as you described.  Yes, the Weather modifier when present affects only the Base income, which is what your Catnip Fields are producing on their own.  Yes, the Upgrade modifier (representing the few Hoe upgrades in the workshop) only affects the Village output, which are the kittens you assign to Farmer jobs on the Village tab.

All modifiers past that are completely global, and apply to the total of the previous incomes, and in fact should stack, each multiplying in turn.  Paragon and Faith bonuses will show up before Buildings when you have them.  I am presuming that where you show "Buildings" in your diagram, is where I see the "Magnetos" or "Reactors" lines in mine; each is a separate multiplier.  An Automated line will appear with a subtraction for anything removed by an automated building (for catnip, Bio Labs), and Demand for your actual kitten chow dinners.

Comment: I double checked the calculation using my existing values and it appears to be so.